# Why does this x86_64 assembly code does not work?

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

```
section .text
    global my_strlen

my_strlen:
    xor rax, rax
.LOOP:
    cmp BYTE[rdi+rax], 0
    jne .LOOP
    inc rax
    ret
```

I execute it with:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern size_t my_strlen(const char *str);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc!=2) return 1;
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)my_strlen(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

But when I execute the program, it does not output anything and it does not close.

Comment: shouldn't the `inc rax` be inside the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increment `rax` in the loop. Otherwise, you always test the same byte.

```
my_strlen:
    xor rax, rax
    dec rax
.LOOP:
    inc rax
    cmp BYTE[rdi+rax], 0
    jne .LOOP
```

Comment: Isn't the INC going to affect the flags?

Answer (score 4):

You need to increment rax inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing rax outside the loop